# WebAPI + MVC + Owin: MVC routes don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have an WebAPI 2 app with OWIN. Now I'm trying to add an MVC 5 controller to everything, but my MVC routes are not being found. I'm receiving the following error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44320/home'.
>
> No type was found that matches the controller named 'home'.

The controller's name is correct (`HomeController`), it is public, and I'm configuring the routes in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    ModelBinderConfig.RegisterModelBinders(config.Services);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I also have the OWIN Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        var globalExceptionHandler = GetGlobalExceptionHandlerConfiguration();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), globalExceptionHandler);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

I've noticed that when I comment out the `app.UseWebApi(config)` line, the MVC routes start to work again.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to register you webapi routes after your mvc routes. This can be done in `Application_Start`, by moving `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` below `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment: I tried and still getting the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `app.UseWebApi()` command is for self-hosting with OWIN, which is incompatible with MVC, so you can only use it when your project is exclusively a Web Api project. Just remove that, and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in your RouteConfig.cs file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've already done that. If I comment out the line that I mentioned, the routes work. So the route is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to move all the configuration from `Application_Start` in post above to `Startup.Configuration` replacing `app.UseWebApi(config);`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in owin startup class.

```
// instead of : app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)    
app.UseWebApi(new HttpConfiguration());
```